# Change button shape html/css

Tags: html, css, button

I'm working on an html project,making a website and i have added a navigation bar/menu by creating buttons for each menu choice.

My button is the black one and i want its shape to become like the red one button.
[image]

here is my code css that sets the shape of my button:

**Ignore the colors.My problem is how to change that shape and nothing else. Any ideas?**

```
li {
    display: inline;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    font-family: Futura, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 1px 1px ;
    background-color: #cc0323
}
```

Comment: You can easily get this kind of information online if you look through. Please do some research and try something at the very least. I'd recommend Mozilla Dev. Network for your front-end needs. For Css you can look here --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css

Comment: thank you. I trusted stackoverflow this time. But, i'll do more search!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sound of the question, you want the shape to change without affecting the text. The best way to achieve this, is the `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements.

```
li {
  border: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Futura, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
li::after {
  content: "'";
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #cc0323;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
-o-transform: skew(-30deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-30deg);
}
```

Here's what it looks like:
http://jsbin.com/aCIQupeJ/2

Comment: yea,both answers are suitable,but this one,with the text normal and the shapes as i want them, solved my whole problems with the text. thanks.

Comment: well, right now i have the above code for my buttons. How can i make it to change the button color ,when i hover over it? @Zeal

Comment: @HpdsbuΖt , I know this question is ancient, but I'll add the answer for posterity. To change a pseudo-element when hovering the parent element, use a selector like `li:hover::after`. The pseudo-element will inherit styles from `li::after` and be overridden by styles from `li:hover::after`. So you only need the properties that will change on hover.

Answer (score 2):

Use **transform:skew** on the **x-axis.**  Ex:

```
transform: skew(-30deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-30deg);
```

should give you about what you want.  However, you cannot use it on **inline** elements, so you'll have to change that (to inline-block, maybe):

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    font-family: Futura, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 1px 1px ;
    background-color: #cc0323
    transform: skew(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/38jfg/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i can understand where to use your commands. Copy and paste them into my existing css code?

Comment: @HpdsbuΖt Replace your code with the one in the answer (`li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    font-family: Futura, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 1px 1px ;
    background-color: #cc0323
    transform: skew(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg);
}`), and change the display to something other than inline.

Comment: @HpdsbuΖt Your welcome.  Please press the white check mark to accept my answer as a bigger thanks :)